Get SMILES from Jsme-component through callback
I am trying to get the SMILES from a JSME component through a callback within a python dash app.
I have been trying this example:
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output
from dash_bio import Jsme

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("JSME Structure Drawing Example", style={'textAlign': 'center'}),
    html.Div([
        Jsme(
            id='jsme-component',
            width="800px",
            height="400px"
        ),
        html.Label("SMILES Output:", style={'marginTop': '20px'}),
        dcc.Textarea(
            id='smiles-output',
            style={
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '100px',
                'marginTop': '10px',
                'fontFamily': 'monospace'
            },
            readOnly=True
        )
    ])
])

@app.callback(
    Output('smiles-output', 'value'),
    Input('jsme-component', 'smiles')  # Expecting the SMILES string from the Jsme component
)
def update_smiles(smiles):
    if not smiles:
        return "No structure drawn yet."
    return smiles

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

I would like the SMILES to fill into the textbox as its drawn or after clicking some button. I would also be happy to understand what I did wrong and where I can find the right callbacks to use for components like jsme. I tried to find documentation through their GitHub etc but did not manage.
Thank you
